# ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 using a typed string vs variable string

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to dynamically perform a simple if statement using data from Sheet1 and placing the result on Sheet2.
The excel if statement is =IF(Sheet1!C2:C35="Sold",Sheet1!A2:A35,"") and works fine, except it is not dynamic.  I can then copy the statement down the page as far as I need. I used the record macro function and got the following:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Sheet1!R[-1]C[-1]:R[32]C[-1]=""Sold"",Sheet1!R[-1]C[-3]:R[32]C[-3],"""")" and copied it down the page.  It also works fine.
```

The issue is when I create a string variable called BuySellRng (as string) and put the same string with variable to make it dynamic it simply returns the string which does not execute the if statement.

```
Sub Macro13()
'
' Test Macro 
'
Dim ir As Long

Dim BuySellRng As String

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ir = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'gets the number of rows which is the variable

'
BuySellRng = """=IF(Sheet1!R[-1]C[-1]:R[" & ir - 3 & "]C[-1]=" & """" & """" & "Sold" & """" & """" & ",Sheet1!R[-1]C[-3]:R[" & ir - 3 _
                        & "]C[-3]," & """" & """" & """" & """" & ")"""

'
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Sheet1!R[-1]C[-1]:R[32]C[-1]=""Sold"",Sheet1!R[-1]C[-3]:R[32]C[-3],"""")"
' the above works
'    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = BuySellRng   'this does not
    
    
    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D3:D34"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("D3:D34").Select
End Sub
```

I would have added my spread sheet but did not know how.

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2 Working not working just displays the if statements

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this alternative code

```
Sub Macro13()
  Dim lLastRow As Long
  
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    With .Range("D2")
      .Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!C2=""Sold"",Sheet1!A2,"""")"
      .Copy
    End With
    .Range(.Range("D3"), .Range("D" & lLastRow)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas    
  End With
  
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Edit: Changed `.Formula2` to `.Formula` as it might cause some version issues.